# Mark an individual Doctrine migration as ran/executed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, database-migration

Is there a way that I can mark a Doctrine migration as "ran" or "executed" in the way that it *won't* be shown as a migration that needs to be migrated?

`app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --add Version20140409203042`

I don't see anything in the `--help`.

The reason for doing this is my DB is up to date and imported from elsewhere, but this migration is asking to be ran every time I run a `doctrine:migrations:migrate`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found that this functionality falls under the `version` command:

Use this command to add a single version:

*Symfony 2/3*

`app/console doctrine:migrations:version 20140430223207 --add`

*Symfony 4*

`bin/console --env=staging doctrine:migrations:version 'Application\Migrations\Version20220803073040' --add`

Use this command to add them all:

`app/console doctrine:migrations:version --add --all`

Comment: and if you want to add all migrations runs app/console `doctrine:migrations:version  --add -all`

Comment: If you're setting up a project fresh for the first time, you can use `console doctrine:schema:create` followed by `console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage && console doctrine:migrations:version --add --all`.

Comment: I had to format the command like:  `symfony console doctrine:migrations:version 'DoctrineMigrations\Version20210902172415' --add`

Answer (score 3):

In your database is table where stored doctrine migrations. You can just add line with version id (20140409203042). Default name of this table is  migration_versions, i think, or you can find name in config (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

It is one possible solutions for doing migrations wihout running it. But you really should control all queries, if it ok. If one, or more are missing, you should do migrations with queries commented out.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Yes, this does work for me but I eventually found out how to add it. Oddly, it _is_ under `--help` but under the `version` command and not `migrate`. I have added another answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of `doctrine` the migration version name contains a namespace [(Skipping Migrations)](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#skipping-migrations)

Now the command may look like this:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:version 'DoctrineMigrations\Version20220407777666' --add
```